# Moving down a folder in working directory

Tags: r, working-directory

I am trying to move down a folder in the working directly in R. For example, I have a working directory of foo/bar and I want to move to foo/bar/subfolder:

```
setwd("/Users/foo/bar")
getwd()
[1] "/Users/foo/bar"
setwd("~/subfolder")
```

I then receive:

> Error in setwd("~/subfolder"): cannot change working directory

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The symbol `~` does not do what you seem to think it does. It does not mean "the current directory". `~` refers to your home directory.

The correct symbol to use for current directory is a period  `.`

So, what you want is

```
setwd("./subfolder")
```

Current operating systems typically assume that if a full path is not provided, then a relative path (i.e. relative to the current directory) will be used by default.  Therefore it is also possible to simply use

```
setwd("subfolder")
```

**A summary of symbols used in paths**

- `.`  = current directory
- `..` = parent of current directory
- `~`  = home directory (*see explanatory note below on home directory*)
- `/` as 1st character = root directory E.g. `setwd("/folder")`
- `/` within the path = separator between directories in path. E.g. `setwd("/folder/subfolder")`
- `\` = In Windows and DOS operating systems *only*, backslash `\` is equivalent to `/`.  If you use this format in R, you will need to use double backslash `\\` to '[escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)' this. E.g., `setwd("C:\\folder\\subfolder")`.  **However**, to maintain compatibility between platforms, it is recommended to stick to using a forward-slash `/` even on windows systems, as this will be converted to the correct path by R.
- Any path that does not begin with one of the above characters is interpreted as being relative to the current directory.

**Explanatory note on 'home' directory**

In Unix-derived and Unix-like operating systems (such as Linux, OsX, BSD) the meaning of `home` directory referred to by `~` is straightforward. The meaning of `~` is defined by the operating system. Depending on the OS, it is usually `/home/<username>` (in Linux and BSD),   `/Users/<username>` (in OS X) or a similar platform-dependent variant. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Default_home_directory_per_operating_system) for a list of definitions for various operating systems.

But in Windows things are slightly different, because the OS does not recognize `"~"` as a valid path. The R for Windows FAQ explains how `expand.path` interprets the home directory on Windows computers thusly,

> The home directory is set as follows: If environment variable R_USER
>   is set, its value is used. Otherwise if environment variable HOME is
>   set, its value is used. After those two user-controllable settings, R
>   tries to find system-defined home directories. It first tries to use
>   the Windows "personal" directory (typically
>   C:\Users\username\Documents). If that fails, if both environment
>   variables HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH are set (and they normally are), the
>   value is ${HOMEDRIVE}${HOMEPATH}. If all of these fail, the current
>   working directory is used.

In my experience, on Windows R most often interprets `"~"` as `"C:\Users\username\Documents"`.  You can find the values of the environment variables with the following commands

```
Sys.getenv("R_USER")
Sys.getenv("HOME")
Sys.getenv("HOMEDRIVE")
Sys.getenv("HOMEPATH")
```

And, you can find out what path `"~"` is interpreted as by using the command

```
normalizePath("~")
```